# NODEmcu Always stating connection failed always

Tags: iot, nodemcu

This is the code I have written for the node mcu

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* host = "*.*.*.*";  
String path = "/cgi-bin/ts.py?field1=";  


const char* ssid = "my_ssid";
const char* pass = "********";

int sensor = A0;

float tempc;
float svoltage;


void setup(void){
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("");

  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
  // Wait for connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(100);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());  
}


void loop() {

  float xval = analogRead(sensor);


  svoltage = (xval*3100.0)/1023;
  tempc = svoltage/10;
  Serial.println(tempc);



  WiFiClient client;
  const int httpPort = 8000;
  if (client.connect(httpPort)) {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    return;
  }

  client.print(String("GET ") + path + String(tempc) + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
               "Host: " + host + "\r\n" + 
               "Connection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n");
  delay(10000);

}
```

I have checked the syntax several time. I don't see any errors in my code. but it never connects to the network eventhough all the other devices can connect to the network. Take a look and tell me where I went wrong.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you made one logical error and one syntax error.
`client.connect()` method takes in two arguments. So that should be 
`client.connect(host,httpPort)` in your case and When your nodemcu is suceessfully connected to the internet. Your program says Connection failed. That is a logical error.
change the if condition to

```
if (!client.connect(host,httpPort)) {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    return;
 }
```